Cohen's d or Cohen's d-like effect size estimate for regression slope?
Can Cohen's d be calculated for the linear regression coefficient associated with a continuous predictor? If so, what is the formula?
I found one question asking this already, with an answer suggesting that it would not be sensible to calculate Cohen's d for a slope.
So if not, what is an appropriate effect size measure which has similar properties, e.g., unbounded? I'm looking for something that's not measuring the amount of variance explained.
Edit: adding a link to a question I found to be related:
Understanding the calculation of the independent samples Cohen's d from t & df

Standardized slope? This is, technically, unbounded.

You can use the standardized regression coefficient ($\beta$) as an effect size.  This will be analogous to $r$, and so it can be easily converted to a Cohen's $d$ if needed.  Note that once in a blue moon, odd conditions will produce a $\beta$ larger than $+/- 1$, in which case you'd need to revise your regression model before using that indicator of effect size.

@Evan requests unbounded, so outside of +/-1 wouldn't be an issue (I think?)

This sounds promising. What about an effect size measure that incorporates standard error? E.g., if I add additional informative covariates, and the SE decreases, I would want the effect size to increase. I found the formula d = b/(se*sqrt(n-k-1)) at https://bio4158-4558-uottawa.github.io/lab_manual/quantifying-effect-size-in-regression-and-power-analysis.html, but I don't know if it is correct. Maybe this is a separate question.

Rolando's suggestion is already the most analogous approach in regression (if standardized measures is what you are after), but I would add that using unstandardized effect sizes could also be useful as well if you want to understand the weighting of each relationship in their original raw values. As an example, suppose we have a regression of writing ability as predicted by reading ability (in terms of their sum scores), then a $\beta = 20$ may indicate that for every one point increase in reading, it elicits a $20$ point increase in writing.

That would be true if unstandardized b = 20.

Cohen actually devotes two entire chapters of his book “Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences” to this subject. I suggest you find it and read it.
The regression coefficient is related to the Pearson product moment coefficient:
$$\beta = r\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$$
$r$ can be directly used as an effect size index (analogous to Cohen’s $d$) and Cohen provides Power tables for $r$.
When comparing two regression results, Cohen suggests using a Fisher z-transform of the Pearson Coefficient:
$$ z = \frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{1+r}{1-r})$$
The effect size index is then:
$$q=|z_1-z_2|$$
Cohen also provides power tables for $q$.
I have never actually used these particular tables (or modern equivalents in e.g. R), since my practical engineering problems are more related to measuring the magnitude of the slope (which I already know that it’s real from physics textbooks), than to hypothesis testing whether there is or is not a slope. The effect size that Cohen designates as “large” for his field of application, would count as “no relevant correlation” in mine. So I can’t help you with its application.
